# Usage of stateside

Tags: word-usage

The following is an extract from a CNBC article:

> Stateside, President Joe Biden clarified on Monday that the United States was not involved in the aborted weekend rebellion.

Stateside appears to derive from WWII US military jargon and probably for that reason it is used to refer to the United States. (Etymonline)

Can stateside be used or has it ever been used with reference to a different country?

For instance a sentence like, ...”Stateside, Macron decided not to get involved in the deal”…

Can stateside be used in the above sentence, could it be misunderstood, or is it just a wrong collocation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, *stateside* is an adverb and means

> in or to the continental U.S. ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stateside))

So no, it cannot be applied to another country, it is specific to the US. If you consider the etymology provided by M-W, you will see that it is formed from

> (United) States + side

The fact that *United* is omitted, does not change the country to which ***the States*** refer.

Also, [Wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stateside) has an interesting usage note:

> This word is ***rare in American English*** except among speakers with extensive international connections (military personnel, expatriates, Canadian English speakers, etc.). American English generally prefers prepositional phrases such as ***in the United States, in the US,*** or ***in America***.

Surprisingly though, this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stateside%3Aeng_us_2019%2Cstateside%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) shows the opposite:

[image]

A statement like

> Stateside, Macron decided not to get involved in the deal.

will mean that (while) in the US, the French president took that decision.

Comment: Excellent answer, but I have one quibble: The fact that the word is rarer in Great Britain doesn't mean that it isn't also rare in the U.S.

Comment: Well, as the Ngram shows, it is actually not that rare after all! Maybe the fact that it is labelled as informal plays a role.

Comment: How can you tell that it's not that rare? Those percentages usually mean practically nothing to me except in relative terms.

Comment: "Stateside" is vanishingly rare on both sides of the pond. Just add any somewhat-common phrase to the nGram to see this: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stateside%3Aeng_us_2019%2Cstateside%3Aeng_gb_2019%2Cin+America&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: "Stateside" (in reference to the US) is pretty common in Canadian English speakers, as Wikipedia says, in my personal experience.

Comment: Stateside returns 19.600.000 hits on Google, and yes it is far less than the 527 million hits that "in America" gives, but I wouldn't say it's rare...